# 毎月の月末 or 毎月末 to represent the last day of every month

Tags: word-choice

I want to say

> The shop will close on the last day of every month.

Which is the correct one in Japanese?

A: 毎月の月末にはその店が閉まる。

B: 毎月末にはその店が閉まる。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are fine, but 毎月の月末には sounds a little redundant to me. You may want to rephrase it as 毎月末に, 毎月の終わりに, 毎月最後に, いつも月末に, etc.

Comment: いつも月末に seems to be ambiguous to me, whether it is for the current month or every month.

Comment: Why? I think saying いつも clearly means it's "every month".

Comment: This shop always closes on the last day (of the current month).

Comment: その店はいつも月末に閉まる means it closes on Nov 31st, Dec 31st, Jan 1st, and so on, just as いつも週末に閉まる means "the store closes always on weekends." Isn't this what you want to say?

Answer (score 1):

B is fine. You can see examples of it [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E6%AF%8E%E6%9C%88%E6%9C%AB).